# How to remove the set key from shower faucet?

Tags: faucet, bathtub

I'm trying to change the diverter valve in my bath/shower tap but I cannot get the key out to enable me to do so. Does anyone have any ideas on how to remove it? I'm also not sure what it's called, but it's the U shaped key that holds the valve in?

It is a Grohe Concetto (25109) tap, and the part I'm trying to replace is diverter valve (48035).

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the drawing and photo I'd have thought you just need to get a small screwdriver or awl in the gap you've shown there, and the one on the other side and gradually work it out, ensuring it stays straight.

If you work it out a bit at a time, alternating sides, make sure to support the side you've just moved, or it may simply pivot on the middle section.

Comment: Use a pair of small screwdrivers and "walk" it out?

Comment: Yes. I *think* that's what I've said. (albeit in a slightly wordier way, to avoid confusion)

Comment: Yes... just looking to affirm that. You're right.